# Build Error while installing snaapy on Apache hadoop 1.2.1

Tags: hadoop, snappy

I am getting an error while building my `snappy`. I followed the steps mentioned below:

1. Download it from http://code.google.com/p/snappy/.
2. Untarred it with command `tar xvzf snappy-1.1.3`
3. Then followed the following commands

> hadoop@HadoopPseudoVM:~$ mv google-snappy-0852af7 snappy1
>       hadoop@HadoopPseudoVM:~$ vi /home/hadoop/.bashrc
>       hadoop@HadoopPseudoVM:~$ exec bash
>       hadoop@HadoopPseudoVM:~$ mvn package -Dsnappy.prefix=/home/hadoop/snappy1

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.433s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 18 16:08:43 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/hadoop). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

The error says that I haven't mentioned the project. How to mention it?